# Angular Filter - Items of which key exists in other array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, javascript-objects

Lets say I have an array:

```
var Array_1 = [ { k:0 }, {k:3} ] ;
var Array_2 = [ { (other keys), k:0 }, { (other keys), k:5 }, ... ];
```

I need to filter items of Array_2 which have `k` in Array_1.

How would I do this with ng-repeat ?

Comment: Some variation of [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: are the arrays sorted?

Comment: No they are not. I think I've got an answer I'll post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash table for the wanted k values and filter then the array if a hash value exists.

```js
var array_1 = [{ k: 0 }, { k: 3 }],
    array_2 = [{ t: 42, k: 0 }, { x: 5, k: 5 }],
    temp = {},
    result;

array_1.forEach(function (a) {
    temp[a.k] = true;
});
result = array_2.filter(function (a) {
    return temp[a.k];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```